# Functions that Find Tokens, Replace Tokens, and Retrieve Property Values from Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

The module has three functions:

1. get_property_from_dict, retrieves a dictionary property's from a given path.
2. token_collect_from_dict, builds a list of tokens and their location from a given dictionary.
3. token_replace_in_dict, replaces a tokens in a dictionary with supplied values.

I want to use these functions in a larger project. I want to use these functions as an opportunity to get feedback on what I'm mucking up. I'm relatively new to Python. All feedback welcome e.g., style, correctness, etc.

This module is also available in the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/adamfortuno/6df68c8624839dcd61f2eb262bb14303

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


import json
import re

from unittest import TestCase
import unittest.mock as mock


def get_property_from_dict(message: dict, path: list):
    """Get Property from Dictionary
    This function retrieves the value of a property at a
    specified location.
    Args:
        message (dict):
            The message the function traverses.
        path (list):
            An ordered list of nested properties or elements. This is
            the structure that identifies a property in a supplied
            message.
            path = ['romania', 'bar', 0, 'this']
            message = {
                "romania": {
                    "region": "transylvania"
                    "bar": [
                            { "this": "Cheia", "that": True},
                            { "this": "Brasov", "that": True}
                            { "this": "Paris", "that": Frue}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
    Returns:
        This function returns a the value of the property at the 
        specified location. The return value's data type can be any
        type.
    """
    for key in path:
        message = message[key]

    return message


def token_collect_from_dict(message: dict, message_path: list = None) -> dict:
    """Collect Tokens from Dictionary
    This function parses a dictionary marking token locations.
    The function returns a list of tokens and their locations
    in a given message.
    Args:
        message (dict):
            The message the function searches for tokens.
        message_path (dict):
            (Optional) An ordered list of nested properties or 
            elements. The path to the message's location in a
            larger dictionary.
            message = {
                "romania": {
                    "region": "transylvania",
                    "dateCreated": "<TOKEN.ANY>"
                    "bar": [
                            { "this": "Cheia", "that": True},
                            { "this": "Brasov", "that": True}
                            { "this": "<TOKEN.ff3c2f>", "that": Frue}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
            token_collect_from_dict(message['romania'], ['romania'])
    Returns:
        The function returns a list of tokens and their locations
        in a given message.
        [
            {'<TOKEN.a3bcf2>': ['romania', 'bar', 2, 'this']},
            {'<TOKEN.ANY>': ['romania', 'dateCreated']}
        ]
    """

    tokens = []
    message_path = [] if message_path is None else message_path

    for key in message.keys():

        path = message_path.copy()
        path.append(key)

        # Replace a token if found
        if type(message[key]) == str:
            res = re.findall('<TOKEN\..*>', message[key])

            if res:
                tokens.append({res[0]: path})

        # If the key is a dictionary, check it for tokens
        elif type(message[key]) == dict:
            res = token_collect_from_dict(message[key], path)

            if res:
                tokens += res

        # If the key is a list, check it for objects or tokens
        elif type(message[key]) == list:

            for element_position in range(len(message[key])):
                object_path = path.copy()

                if type(message[key][element_position]) == dict:
                    object_path.append(element_position)
                    res = token_collect_from_dict(
                        message[key][element_position], object_path)

                    if res:
                        tokens += res

    return tokens


def token_replace_in_dict(message: dict, tokens: dict) -> dict:
    """Replace Tokens
    This function replaces tokens in a given dictionary.
    Args:
        message (dict):
            The message the function searches for tokens.
        tokens (dict):
            The tokens the function searches for. The token dict
            includes tokens and values.
    Returns:
        The original dictinary with tokens replaced with
        token values. For example, the following message:
        {
            'kid': 'Sabrina',
            'incidents': [
                {'description': 'jump on desk', 'dateOccurred': '<TOKEN.ANY>'},
                {'description': 'paint on wall', 'dateOccurred': '<TOKEN.a3bcf2>'}
            ]
        }
        
        The following token bank:
        { "<TOKEN.ANY>": mock.ANY, "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>": '1234' }
        Results in the following output:
        {
            'kid': 'Sabrina',
            'incidents': [
                {'description': 'jump on desk', 'dateOccurred': <ANY>},
                {'description': 'paint on wall', 'dateOccurred': '1234'}
            ]
        }
    """

    for key in message.keys():
        # Replace a token if found
        if type(message[key]) == str and message[key] in tokens.keys():
            message[key] = tokens[message[key]]

        # If the key is a dictionary, check it for tokens
        elif type(message[key]) == dict:
            message[key] = \
                token_replace_in_dict(message[key], tokens)

        # If the key is a list, check it for objects or tokens
        elif type(message[key]) == list:
            for element_position in range(len(message[key])):
                if type(message[key][element_position]) == dict:
                    message[key][element_position] = \
                        token_replace_in_dict(message[key][element_position], tokens)

    return message

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    test_dictionary_1 = {
        "name": "Ralphy",
        "record": [
            {"crime": "jump on desk", "occurrences": 2},
            {"crime": "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>", "occurrences": 1},
        ],
        "age": {
            "years": "<TOKEN.ANY>",
            "thinger": {
                "thang1": "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>",
                "thang2": "sabrina",
                "thang3": [
                    {"foo": "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>", "bar": True}
                ],
            }
        }
    }

    test_dictionary_2 = {
        "kid": "Sabrina",
        "incidents": [
            {"description": "jump on desk", "dateOccurred": "<TOKEN.ANY>"},
            {"description": "paint on wall", "dateOccurred": "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>"},
        ]
    }

    token_bank = {
        "<TOKEN.ANY>": mock.ANY,
        "<TOKEN.a3bcf2>": '1234',
    }
    print(test_dictionary_2)
    print(token_replace_in_dict(test_dictionary_2, token_bank))
    #print(get_property_from_dict(test_dictionary_1, ('record', 0, 'crime')))
    #print(token_collect_from_dict(test_dictionary_1))
```

Comment: A list can never be a key

Answer (score 3):

The type hints here:

```
def get_property_from_dict(message: dict, path: list):
```

are a little tricky. The function could technically accept a dict with keys and values of any type, so you can't probably do much better than `dict`. For `path`, `list` is too specific - you can accept any `Iterable`. The return value, rather than being unspecified, should probably be indicated as `Any`.

That function is an excellent candidate for [docstring tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) and only requires a little reformatting on your part to get there.

This example:

```json
            message = {
                "romania": {
                    "region": "transylvania",
                    "dateCreated": "<TOKEN.ANY>"
                    "bar": [
                            { "this": "Cheia", "that": True},
                            { "this": "Brasov", "that": True}
                            { "this": "<TOKEN.ff3c2f>", "that": Frue}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
```

is malformed in at least two ways - "Frue", and imbalanced braces. I'm having difficulty understanding what `token_collect_from_dict` even does, given that I don't think the input and output examples properly correspond to each other. Docstring tests will help with this.

This:

```
for key in message.keys():
```

does not need `.keys()` since key iteration is the default.

Do not determine types like this:

```
type(message[key]) == dict
```

Instead, call `isinstance`.

`message[key][element_position]` should be given a temporary variable.